# Why is my code shown as messy while it isn't?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encode, urlfetch

```
class sss(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    url = "http://www.google.com/"
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url)    
    if result.status_code == 200:
        self.response.out.write(result.content)
```

When I change code to this:

```
if result.status_code == 200:
        self.response.out.write(result.content.decode('utf-8').encode('gb2312'))
```

It shows something strange. What should I do?

When I use this:

```
self.response.out.write(result.content.decode('big5'))
```

The page is different with the one I saw Google.com.

How to get Google.com that I saw?

Comment: Having not been to Google's homepage today, I was seriously confused how Pacman factored into this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is probably serving you ISO-8859-1.  At least, that is what they serve me for the User-Agent "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" (which urlfetch uses).  The Content-Type header value is:

```
text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

So you would use:

```
result.content.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

If you check `result.headers["Content-Type"]`, your code can adapt to changes on the other end.  You can generally pass the charset (ISO-8859-1 in this case) directly to the Python decode method.

Answer (score 1):

> how to get google.com that i saw ?

It's probably using relative URLs to images, javascript, CSS, etc, that you're not changing into absolute URLs into google's site.  To confirm this: your logs should be showing 404 errors ("page not found") as the browser to which you're serving "just the HTML" tries locating the relative-addressed resources that you're not supplying.